# How to enforce lowercase for all data in specific column?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
```

I'm looking for a way to enforce lowercase for the `name` values.

For example, when I save a record using this command:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('JOHN');
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('John');
```

I want it to be saved as `john` without converting the case beforehand using my programming language i.e. JavaScript, Ruby and etc.

Is it possible to make use of `LOWER()` function inside this `CREATE TABLE` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) for that:

```
create function make_lower_name() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.name := lower(new.name);
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger ensure_lower_name_trg
   before update or insert on users
   for each row
   execute procedure make_lower_name();
```

Comment: Where should I run this? In `psql` console?

Comment: Yes, it's two DDL statements. One to create the trigger function and one to create the trigger.

Comment: What if I want to apply this for many columns? Do I just need to add `new.xxx := lower(new.xxx);` between the `begin` and the `end;`?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin: yes

Comment: I got this error - https://pastebin.com/raw/Nc7cLXj9 - any idea?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin: sorry, I forgot the line `return new;` (and please do link to external sites for errors - you could have easily copied & pasted that error message as text)

Comment: I can confirm that it's now working. Thank you. Anyway, the error is on Pastebin website. It's text. :)